# Plugin defined with Hybrid lifecycle being instantiated more than once per HttpContext

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, .net-3.5, dependency-injection, structuremap

I have a standard StructureMap-based ControllerFactory setup, and I have Controllers that have various dependencies that each have a dependency of type `IRepository`, like so:

```
// "web" assembly
public StructureMapRegistry : Registry 
{
    public StructureMapRegistry()
    {
        Scan(scanner =>
                     {
                         scanner.AssemblyContainingType<WidgetController>();
                         scanner.AssemblyContainingType<Repository>();
                         scanner.WithDefaultConventions();
                     });

        For<IRepository>().HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped().Use<Repository>();
    }
}

public WidgetController(IService1 service1, IService2 service2, Service3 service3)
{
    // etc, etc
}

// "data" assembly
public Service1 : IService1
{
    public Service1(IRepository repository)
    {
        // etc, etc
    }
}

public Service2 : IService2
{
    public Service2(IRepository repository)
    {
        // etc, etc
    }
}

public Service3
{
    public Service3(IRepository repository)
    {
        // etc, etc
    }
}
```

Using debugging and `GetHashCode()` and the like, it seems that there's a new `Repository` being instantiated in each of the services when the `WidgetController`, when I am expecting them to all use the the same instance.

Am I misunderstanding what `HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped()` does? Is it because I'm sometimes passing in concrete classes instead of interfaces as dependences, like I did with `Service3` in the code above (IRepository is ALWAYS used, never the Repository concrete class)? Am I just completely doing this wrong?

(This code was obviously extrapolated from the actual code, so I hope I didn't leave out any important details.)

NOTE: I am using StructureMap 2.6.1.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have posted is correct, you should be getting the same instance of IRepository throughout your request.  There must be something else going on that you have not included in your question...